# Essential roles for web application team

Tags: project-management

Some friends of mine came up with an idea for a web application which we (so far) think could be great. I made the analysis and all the early stages of the development process and I'm about to start the coding. I'm talking about something that is barely a mid-level project, so I consider one developer (myself) should be enough.

The thing is that we are trying to assign roles to each one of us so we can be focused on our duties and have clear our responsibilities within the team. We are a crew of four people, three of us (my friends) are business people who would do the marketing, customer relationship, management and accounting stuff and I'm basically the developer. I have in mind to get them involved into the development process by giving them documentation to write and use them as testers, all of that besides the management duties they have.

Perhaps someone out there have been in the same situation, so I would appreciate if the experience is shared so we can effectively give ourselves positions in the project based on what I explained above. Which are the essential roles or the optimal team layout so the idea can be developed successfully? The question is not strictly about programming, but it's related to build a software entrepreneurship beyond the code, that is something that I'm sure plenty of us are looking.

Any help is really appreciated! Regards.

Comment: Without knowing what kind of web app it is, it's pretty difficult to say. (E.g. Some generate a lot of customer service, some have credit card payments involved, some require tons of moderation etc).  Also in my opinion 4 is a large denominator when only 1 is doing any development work.

Comment: Your question would probably be better to be asked on  programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. What I tend to do is think about responsibilities in terms of "functional" vs "technical" and go from there. "Functional" responsibilities and requirements reflect the customer, the user, the stakeholders and are usually technology agnostic. "Technical" responsibilities and requirements translate the functional items into architectures, platforms, technical relationships, coding languages, etc.

Here are some possible functional roles your partners can fill to support your development role:

**Project Manager**: Ultimately responsible for timelines, budgets, and delivery of projects / sprints and product delivery.

**Business Analysts**: Collect customer requirements for the software. This role usually requires subject matter and market expertise or access to such expertise. They ultimately write the functional specs that your technical specs will be derived from.

**Product Manager**: This role compliments the marketing efforts by ensuring that first and all future iterations of the product are meeting market and customer needs. They have full responsibility for bridging that gap between functional and technical.

I think what you mentioned about also using them to write documentation and test is a great idea, as it will help them understand the development time and effort required from your job, and allow them to speak intelligently to the more technical aspects of the product, even if they are not techies themselves.

They could also play a big role in helping construct the user experience, by storyboarding and wire-framing.

Good luck!